# SIFR 3 Beta: Has Anyone been able to text-align right?

Tags: text, sifr

SIFR 3 Beta is working so well for me except for the text alignment tag. Is it just me or it is possible that it is a bug?

I will post some details soon. In the meantime, let me know if you succeeded aligning right or center.

Comment: Thanks Mark! "fitExactly" was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `fitExactly` `text-align` won't work. Other than that it should be fine.

I'm assuming you're using r436?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks Mark!

see it in action here: www.parcemusik.com

Comment: forceSingleLine will break the text-align property also